# Using scikit LinearRegression.predict for multifeature labels

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make predictions about the number of customers at a restaurant (=label) at a certain weekday (0-6) and a time, using them as features. My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

My sketch at making my model predict the number of customers at the first data point available, the first row, is this:

```
deg = 10 #the chosen polynomial degree
lin_regr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False) #linregr object
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg)    #polynomial model
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train) # fit the features
lin_regr.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
print(lin_regr.predict([df.iloc[0]['weekday'], df.iloc[0]['acchour']])) 
#The last line is causing the error
```

However, I'm getting

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[1.   6.75]
```

What is the reason behind this, and what is the proper syntax to feed the two features into the function `predict()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your datapoint has the shape (2,) and it needs to be (2,1).
Try:

```
import numpy as np
datapoint=np.array([df.iloc[0]['weekday'], df.iloc[0]['acchour']]).reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: I'm still getting ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 66 is different from 1) ; do you have any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: Ahm, you need to run it through the preprocessing as well I think.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Turning the features to_numpy()?

Comment: @Kurns no, passing the data through `poly.transform` first; remember, whatever preprocessing you are doing on your *training* data you are expected to do for your future (test & unseen) data, too.